# How to change the parsing?

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I have the following json :

```kotlin
{
"id":"123",
"nbElements":15,
"containers":[
  {
    "id":"cont1",
    "capacity":3
  }
],
"operations":[
  {
    "id":"cont1_01",
    "weight":3,
    "containerId":"cont1"
  },
  {
    "id":"cont1_02",
    "weight": 4, 
    "containerId":"cont1"
  }
]
}
```

I created the following classes:

```kotlin
data class Instance (
    val id: String,
    val nbElements: Long,
    val containers: List<Container>,
    val operations: List<Operation>
)

data class Container (
    val id: String,
    val capacity: Long
)

data class Operation (
    val id: String,
    val weight: Long,
    val containerId: String
)
```

And I am parsing it using Moshi

```kotlin
val adapter = Moshi.Builder().addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build().adapter<Instance>(Instance::class.java)`
val instance: Instance? = adapter.fromJson(request)
```

N.B `request` here is just the json object sent by an API or a Message-oriented middleware

However, I am  not happy with that for several reasons.

First, I want to use a HashMap for `containers` and `operations` where the keys are the identifiers. Thus I will be able to access an operation object easily using its key.

Second, I want to store the container as a full object in each operation. Thus I can do thins like `operation.container.capacity`

Any ideas on improving my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use different models for different layers of the application.
For example:

**Remote Model:**

```kotlin
data class InstanceRemoteModel (
    val id: String,
    val nbElements: Long,
    val containers: List<Container>,
    val operations: List<Operation>
)

data class ContainerRemoteModel (
    val id: String,
    val capacity: Long
)

data class OperationRemoteModel (
    val id: String,
    val weight: Long,
    val containerId: String
)
```

**DomainModel:**

```kotlin
data class Instance (
    val id: String,
    val elementCount: Long,
    val containers: Map<String, Container>,
    val operations: Map<String, Operation>
)

data class Container (
    val id: String,
    val capacity: Long
)

data class Operation (
    val id: String,
    val weight: Long,
    val container: Container
)
```

You can a have repository layer wherein you can convert remote models to domain models. Something like so:

```kotlin
class InstanceRepository(...) {
    suspend fun getInstance(...) : Instance {
        //Get data from Server
        //Map models using mapper classes/functions

        return instance
    }
}
```

Now, in your `ViewModel` you can access data from the repository.

Note that the above example is just for sake of demonstration. You can tailor your code as you like. The example demonstrates that you are not restricted to the form of data you receive from a remote source and that you can design your model as you require for your application. Data from a remote source is designed so as to efficiently transfer data and is not necessarily how the client application requires it.

Here are useful resources for better understanding:

1. [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)
2. [Repository pattern](https://proandroiddev.com/the-real-repository-pattern-in-android-efba8662b754)
3. [Functional data mappers](https://proandroiddev.com/functional-data-mappers-4daf495192ed)

Comment: what do you mean by `view model` ?

Comment: Its a part of a type of architecture called [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)

Comment: Do you think it's better to use a map than to use a list and then use a `find` on this list to access an element with a specified identifier ?

Comment: Any idea how to test it ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had replied to your previous comment. Using the map vs list depends on the use case, either one can be suitable. Just for the purpose of searching, I guess map would be better. Anyways, you should look into how each one works.

Comment: What do you mean? "Any idea how to test it ?"